# How to test file upload with factorygirl?

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I want to test a model with a basic file upload which does not use a plugin (I think it was a bad idea at the time but know I have to deal with tons of existing documents).

The thing is that I want to test the size of the uploaded file, so I need to access to the `temfile` attribute of `file` which is a ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile

It works quite well in my controllers but I can't find how to make my factory pass.

Attachment Model:

```
attr_accessor :file # file_field_tag name
attr_accessible :file, :filename # store the filename in the db

before_save :upload_file

def upload_file
  if self.file && File.size(self.file.tempfile) < 10.megabytes
    puts self.file.class.inspect # see below
    File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/files/" + self.filename.to_s, 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(self.file.read)
    end
    ensure_file_presence
  end
end
```

FactoryGirl Attachment:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :attachment do
    filename 'anyfile.txt'
    file ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(:tempfile => "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/anyfile.txt", :filename => "anyfile.txt")
  end
end
```

When I run tests, a `FactoryGirl.build :attachment` will succeed but with a `create` will fail.

Strange observation: I've displayed the `self.file` class before the File.open and it is seen as a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`, then I have an error on `self.file.read`: it has changed into a String.

```
puts self.file.class.inspect
=> ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile

f.write(self.file.read) => NoMethodError: undefined method `read' for #<String:0x007ff50f70f6a0>
```

I've read other posts that suggest I should use `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` or `fixture_file_upload` but I can't make it work, as the tempfile won't exists of any of these 2 solutions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see one issue. UpLoadedFile (`:tempfile`) is expecting a File not a String. For you observation, it never changed into a String you defined it as a String. You need to surround it with a `File.new()` as shown below. You need to put the file there before you try to run the test. Hope this helps!

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :attachment do
    file ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(:tempfile => File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/anyfile.txt"), :filename => "anyfile.txt")
  end
end
```

Comment: You just made my day! Thks!